# What is wrong with this trigger?

Tags: trigger

Trigger Noob here trying to finish my first trigger... thanks for bearing with me!
Why am I getting the following error when trying to save this trigger?

> Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'E000000092pN' at line 3 column 34

```
   trigger NewEnrollee on Contact (after insert) {
        for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {
            if (con.RecordTypeId = 012E000000092pN) {
                Enrollment_Process__c ep : new Enrollment_Process__c();
                ep.Student_Name__c = con.Id;
                ep.RecordTypeId    = '012E000000092pX';
                insert ep;
            }
        }
    }
```

The business requirement I am trying to satisfy is: any time a Contact of the record type "Student" is created, a "New Enrollment Process" record should also be created associated to the new Student.
012E000000092pN is the record type id for "Student" Contacts.
012E000000092pX is the record type id for "New Enrollment" (custom object Enrollment_Process__c has two record types: New Enrollment and Re-Enrollment. I need the newly created enrollment process record to be of the record type "New Enrollment").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to wrap Id in quote `'` and use `==` instead of single `=`. Should be:

```
if (con.RecordTypeId == '012E000000092pN') {
....
....
}
```

Apart of this, it is not recommended to use hardcoding of Ids in code. You should query Id from the `RecordType` object.

You can get record type Id this way:

```
// RecordTypeLabel is name of Record Type e.eg: New-Enrollment or Student.
Id newEnrollId = Schema.Sobjecttype.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RecordTypeLabel').getRecordTypeId();`
```

**AND**

> Do not preform DML in for loop. This is bad way. Always use `List` and
>   then perform DML operation on List. As `insert listOfNewEnrollRecs;`

Comment: Use double equal to if
 (con.RecordTypeId == '012E000000092pN')

Comment: Thanks @RobertBarnett for pointing out :) Edited answer as per you advice.

Comment: Line 4 also had an error! I used `:` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do any bulk processing in your trigger, never perform DML or SOQL in for loop.

And you have forgot to wrap Id in quote:

Your code should look like below:

```
trigger NewEnrollee on Contact (after insert) {
    List<Enrollment_Process__c> enrollmentProcessList = New List<Enrollment_Process__c>();
    for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {
        if (con.RecordTypeId.equalsIgnoreCase('012E000000092pN')) {
            Enrollment_Process__c ep : new Enrollment_Process__c();
            ep.Student_Name__c = con.Id;
            ep.RecordTypeId    = '012E000000092pX';
            enrollmentProcessList.add(ep);
        }
    }
    if(!enrollmentProcessList.isEmpty()){
        INSERT enrollmentProcessList;
    }
}
```

Comment: aside from the hardcoded ids as pointed out elsewhere; `equalsIgnoreCase(..) on an ID field is unnecessary as IDs are, in fact, case sensitive